# Which event is fired on Ctrl+mouse left click and how i can check in my any function

Tags: javascript

```
For example :
  myFunction(event) {
    if(event is "Ctrl+mouse left" ) {
      console.log('it works');
    }
  }
```

only want to know how I can track this event in javascript

Comment: Do you have any code to show? Anything you tried but does not work? Then please provide a JsFiddle.

This platform is not intended to be a platform where other users code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the combination of this two events:

```
   event.ctrlKey
```

is=true if the CTRL key is pressed

```
   event.button
```

is=0 if the left mouse button is clicked